# Can I join two armatures so that the bones keep their animations?

Tags: animation, armature

So, I was playing around with armatures, and at some point I had two armatures, which were both animated. Is there a way to join the bones together, so that they keep their animations?

Comment: You need to join the actions assigned to the armatures and apply this action to the final armature. Make sure the bone names are unique.